# Set zero height to constraintLayout child programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, layoutparams

How can I set the height of a ConstraintLayout child to be 0dp?
When I use layoutParams and do the following, ConstraintLayout thinks 0dp = match_parent

```kotlin
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams.apply {
            this.height = newHeight
        }
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

So if newHeight is 0 here, it thinks it's match_parent

I would like to avoid checking for 0 and if true set it to a negative value

Comment: maybe it will be easier to use visibility change param?

Comment: 0dp == match_parent only if the view is constrained to top & bottom of the parent view. What is your goal here?

Comment: 0 dp means put it into constraint if you constrainted your layout between bottom and top of the page it will act like match_parent maybe you should quit constrainting  between top and bottom.

Comment: @gioravered I 'm collapsing some views inside a callback (AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener). Is there no way to tell ConstraintLayout that a view has zero height then?

Comment: @Andrew, I would like to avoid these checks, but if there is no solution, I 'll fallback to checking if the newHeight is zero, and make it -5 or something

Comment: I 'll see if can remove the top and bottom constraints

Comment: You can also remove just the bottom or just the top

Comment: Yup, it worked, thanks!
If you want make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it

Comment: No worries.. Glad it worked.